# How to modify to promise.all JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I'm trying to make some changes.
I have a search code in searchBar and with it a call to an API.json to fetch the information and put it on the site. Everything works fine, however I would like to modify it to add a Promise.all and be able to call more than one API and be able to display it on the site. But all my attempts have failed.

what do i have in js:

```
const localList = document.getElementById('localList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
let hpWords = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filteredWords = hpWords.filter((words) => {
        return (
            words.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    displayCharacters(filteredWords);
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://duhnunes.github.io/api/local.json');
        hpWords = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(hpWords);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (words) => {
    const htmlString = words
        .map((character) => {
            return `
            <div class="voc-box-content">
                <h5>${character.name} - ${character.trans} [${character.type} - ${character.type2}]</h5>
                <p>${character.description}</p>
            </div>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
        localList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadCharacters();
```

To display on the page I am using `<div id="localList"></div>`.
 In the example I am displaying `local.json` and I would also like to display `item.json` with `<div id ="itemList"></div>`.
Both have the same display structure on the `<div class="voc-box-content">...</div>` site.

Cheers,
DuH

Comment: Please include or describe an example of what you tried or explain more clearly where you are trying to use `Promise.all`

Comment: @MrCodingB I just tried to change `const res = await fetch('https://duhnunes.github.io/api/local.json');` to `const res = await Promise.all([ fetch('https://duhnunes.github.io/api/local.json'), fetch('https://duhnunes.github.io/api/item.json');]);`. Also add `hpItem = await res2.json();` and `itemList.innerHTML = htmlString;` and duplicated every part that "reads" (I think) json `const displayCharacters = (words) => {...};`. But it doesn't seem to be as simple as in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch words from multiple apis you can use this:

```js
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const lists = {
  localList: {
    api: 'api1'
  },
  miscList: {
    api: 'api2'
  },
  ...
};

Object.entries(lists).forEach(([id, list]) => {
  list.element = document.getElementById(id);
});

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

  Object.values(lists).forEach((list) => {
    list.filteredWords = list.words.filter((word) => {
      return word.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
    });
  });

  displayCharacters();
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
  try {
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(lists).map(async (list) => {
        const response = await fetch(list.api);
        list.words = await response.json();
      })
    );

    displayCharacters();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const displayCharacters = () => {
  Object.values(lists).forEach((list) => {
    list.element.innerHTML = (list.filteredWords ?? list.words)
      .map((word) => `
        <div class="voc-box-content">
          <h5>${word.name} - ${word.trans} [${word.type} - ${word.type2}]</h5>
          <p>${word.description}</p>
        </div>`)
      .join('');
  });
};

loadCharacters();
```

Comment: OP might care about the order of the results. By `push`ing inside the async callbacks, the order is not necessarily the same order as in the `apiEndpoints` array.

Comment: Oh, cool, and how would I print both? I was using the `localList.innerHTML = htmlString;`to print on `<div id="localList"></div>`. But now it doesn't print anymore. `response` appears dark, like no other use, in vscode. I tried to use it to print, but it remained unprinted on the website. with the code below `const displayCharacters = (words) => {..}).join('');localList.innerHTML = htmlString;};`

Comment: Your display characters function shouldn't have to change

Comment: @DHU or do you want to display the words in seperate lists?

Comment: @DHU I noticed I had a typo in the map function of the first example...it should be `awair response.json()` instead of `await r.json()`

Comment: @MrCodingB sry, i maked +- what i have(i should have done this before but i'm silly) sry:  https://codepen.io/duhnunes/pen/XWgRPZE .. Yeah, i want print in different locations

Comment: And where in your codepen should the other words from the other apis be

Comment: each api will appear in a different tab. localList to LOCAL, itemList to ITEM miscList to MISC. I use `<div id="localList"></div>` inside the LOCAL tab to print.

Comment: i use `const localList = document.getElementById('localList');` and `localList.innerHTML = htmlString;` and `<div id="localList"></div>` to print

Comment: would it be nice to know the structure of json? I make this `[{"name": "Ratway","trans":Toca do Rato","type": "Local","type2": "","description": "test from test"}`

Comment: I updated my answer, this should do the trick

Comment: `'}' expected. ts[1005) [70, 18]` > `search.js[30,44]: The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.` is giving this error. I tried to close just above `loadCharacters();` and/or line 39, but there was no effect.

Comment: I think I fixed it...try it again

Comment: Didn't show up. So I deleted the duplicate line `const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');` and now works! :D You're the best! thx so much  https://codepen.io/duhnunes/pen/XWgRPZE

Comment: You could actually replace your entire JavaScript with the code I posted in the answer...you don't need any other parts

Comment: lol incredible, ty. only a question: can i change the json file structure without problem or change the whole js? i mean, just replacing some variable?

Comment: If you adjust your print function, yes

Comment: Cool, i have a separate "alphabetical sort" and i think i will have to change the json structure to work. ty again. (: